# Android application ignoring users App Permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, user-permissions

I've been using an application on my device and it allows access to both my camera and gallery even though I have denied access to both. In the applications permission tab, both Camera and Storage are deactivated.

The application is a popular Taxi app and my understanding was that if I deny the application permission to access content/sensors on my device, it would not allow the application access. This somehow overrides it.

My question is, is this a bug on the developers side or with Android itself? In my opinion it's pretty concerning with regards to user privacy. I've had a read through the [Android Permissions Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) and it states

> "...that no app, by default, has permission to perform any operations
>   that would adversely impact other apps, the operating system, or the
>   user."

Which causes cause for concern as the application, by default has access to other apps.

To clarify the app's core functionality doesn't need access to my gallery or camera. I've also replicated this issue on numerous devices with different Android versions and the problem still persists.

Comment: Please give a reason as to down voting a genuine question...

Comment: This is not possible. If permissions are off in settings then app can never access your gallery/location/camera.

Comment: Exactly what I thought, I will escalate this to the developer and Android

Comment: Which Android Version are you using and also state the target sdk version of your app. One thing is that it must be throwing android camera intent which is not part of App but is part of Android.

Comment: Android Version = 9 and Target Sdk Version = 28. Worth pointing out that i am not developing the application. It's an application i've downloaded from the Play Store